# Sorting columns in Flutter datatable

Tags: flutter, firebase, flutter-datatable

I have a datatable in Flutter which display data from a Firebase database. It includes two columns namely 'Registration Date' and 'Expiry Date' which I was to sort when the user taps on the respective columns. Moreover, I have used DateFormat('dd-MM-yyyy') to format the dates, so those are stored as strings in my database.

[This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bJIMo.png) is one such entry in my database and [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lDP2N.jpg) is how the columns look in the DataTable.

```
import 'dart:math';

import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:firebase_database/firebase_database.dart';
import 'package:firebase_core/firebase_core.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:intl/intl.dart';
import 'package:sub_mgmt/page/addnewpage.dart';
import 'package:sub_mgmt/page/data/users.dart';
import 'package:sub_mgmt/page/model/user.dart';

import 'editpage.dart';

class MemberList extends StatefulWidget {
  const MemberList({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<MemberList> createState() => MemberListState();
}

class MemberListState extends State<MemberList> {
  static int counter = 1;

  // Reading data from firebase
  CollectionReference _referenceMembers =
      FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('users');
  late Stream<QuerySnapshot> _streamMembers;
  List<int> selectedIndex = [];
  List<String> selectedDocID = [];

  final searchController = TextEditingController();


  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _streamMembers = _referenceMembers.snapshots();
  }

  int? sortColumnIndex;
  bool isAscending = false;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
          stream: _streamMembers,
          builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
            if (snapshot.hasError) {
              return Center(child: Text(snapshot.error.toString()));
            }

            if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.active) {
              QuerySnapshot querySnapshot = snapshot.data;
              List<QueryDocumentSnapshot> listQueryDocumentSnapshot =
                  querySnapshot.docs;
              counter = 0;
              return ScrollableWidget(
                child: Column(
                  children: [
                    DataTable(
                      sortAscending: isAscending,
                      sortColumnIndex: sortColumnIndex,
                      columns: [
                        DataColumn(
                          label: Text(
                            'Sr',
                            style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                          ),
                        ),
                        DataColumn(
                          label: Text(
                            'Name',
                            style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                          ),
                        ),
                        DataColumn(
                          label: Text(
                            'Phone',
                            style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                          ),
                        ),
                        DataColumn(
                          label: Text(
                            'Plan',
                            style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                          ),
                        ),
                        DataColumn(
                          label: Text(
                            'Fee Paid',
                            style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                          ),
                        ),
                        DataColumn(
                          label: Text(
                            'Reg. Date',
                            style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                          ),
                          onSort: onSort,
                        ),
                        DataColumn(
                          label: Text(
                            'Expiry Date',
                            style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                          ),
                          onSort: onSort,
                        ),
                        DataColumn(
                          label: Text(
                            '',
                            style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ],
                      rows: listQueryDocumentSnapshot
                          .map((element) => DataRow(
                                selected: selectedDocID.contains(element.id),
                                onSelectChanged: (isSelected) => setState(() {
                                  final isAdding =
                                      isSelected != null && isSelected;

                                  if (isAdding) {
                                    selectedDocID.add(element.id);
                                  } else {
                                    selectedDocID.remove(element.id);
                                  }
                                }),
                                cells: <DataCell>[
                                  DataCell(Text((++counter).toString())),
                                  DataCell(Text(element['Name'])),
                                  DataCell(Text(element['Phone'].toString())),
                                  DataCell(Text(element['Plan'].toString())),
                                  DataCell(
                                      Text(element['Fee Paid'].toString())),
                                  DataCell(Text(element['Registration Date'])),
                                  DataCell(Text(element['Expiry Date'])),
                                  DataCell(IconButton(
                                    splashRadius: 22,
                                    color: Colors.black38,
                                    icon: Icon(Icons.edit),
                                    onPressed: () {
                                      Navigator.push(
                                        context,
                                        MaterialPageRoute(
                                          builder: (context) => EditPage(
                                              element.id,
                                              element['Name'],
                                              element['Phone'],
                                              element['Plan'],
                                              element['Fee Paid'],
                                              element['Registration Date']),
                                        ),
                                      );
                                    },
                                  ))
                                ],
                              ))
                          .toList(),
                      columnSpacing: 32,
                    ),
                    SizedBox(height: 80),
                  ],
                ),
              );
            }

            return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
          }),
      floatingActionButtonLocation: FloatingActionButtonLocation.endDocked,
      floatingActionButton: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(18.0),
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
          children: [
            Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 8.0),
              child: FloatingActionButton(
                onPressed: () {
                  if (selectedDocID.isNotEmpty) {
                    showDialog(
                        context: context,
                        builder: (BuildContext context) {
                          return AlertDialog(
                            title: Text("Delete"),
                            content: Text("Delete Data?"),
                            shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15)),
                            actions: [
                              TextButton(
                                  onPressed: () {
                                    Navigator.of(context).pop();
                                  },
                                  child: Text("No")),
                              TextButton(
                                  onPressed: () {
                                    for (var i in selectedDocID) {
                                      final docUser = FirebaseFirestore.instance
                                          .collection('users')
                                          .doc(i);
                                      docUser.delete();
                                    }
                                    Navigator.of(context).pop();
                                  },
                                  child: Text("Yes"))
                            ],
                          );
                        });
                  }
                },
                tooltip: 'Delete',
                elevation: 4.0,
                child: Icon(Icons.delete),
              ),
            ),
            FloatingActionButton(
              onPressed: () {
                Navigator.push(context,
                    MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => AddNewPage()));
              },
              tooltip: 'Add',
              elevation: 4.0,
              child: Icon(Icons.add),
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  void onSort(int columnIndex, bool ascending) async {

    setState(() {
      this.sortColumnIndex = columnIndex;
      this.isAscending = ascending;
    });
  }
}

class ScrollableWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  final Widget child;
  const ScrollableWidget({
    Key? key,
    required this.child,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SingleChildScrollView(
      physics: BouncingScrollPhysics(),
      scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
      child: SingleChildScrollView(
        physics: BouncingScrollPhysics(),
        scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
        child: child,
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

I understand that I need to use the `onSort` property of DataColumn, but I'm facing difficulty in implementing it.  Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

> I have used DateFormat('dd-MM-yyyy') to format the dates, so those are stored as strings in my database.

Strings are sorted in Firestore (and most databases) in [lexicographical order](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexicographic_order), and in the data format you've chosen that is different from the chronological order of the dates they represent.

To fix this problem at its root, either store actual `Timestamp` or `Date` values, or (if you persist in storing it as a string) use a date format that is suitable for ordering, such as [ISO-8601](https://www.iso.org/iso-8601-date-and-time-format.html): "yyyy-MM-dd".